# Java Serializable confuse

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, serialization

Recently, our project has to be redesign. But when I use JAVA's interface Serializable, I spend a lot time.

Now, there are two program:A and B.

1. A is offline, it function is transform JSON data to class **C**.
2. Then Serialize C and store it in redis(now C is an object)
3. B get the object, deserialize it , and transform it to C

but it doesn't work. In log information, I found that, **the C class in also A and B must have the same dir**.That is to say, When I put C in A with the package dir "com.hello.src.a", in B with package dir "com.world.src.b" ,the B program will throw a ClassNotFoundException, because B's JVM find C with the dir "com.hello.src.a"!

When I put C in A and B with the same package dir, it works. I want to know that if there's a better way to solve this problem. When I deserializable, I specific the package dir in B program to find the class C(like I tell B's JVM to find C with the package dir "com.world.src.b" )

Comment: I am unable to understand, could you brief little detail.

Comment: That sure is confusing; I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Why not just store the JSON directly in the database rather than storing it as a serialized java-object?

Comment: because the performance is too low. B program is online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying classes from one package to another is completely pointless and is the cause of problems like this. Decide which package you want class `C` to be in and leave it there, use it where it is.

Comment: But A and B aren't in a project. So, they don't share the C class. On the other hand, A and B are different program. So they have the different package dir. When I put the C in the same package dir, the A or B have to create useless package dir.

Comment: I can only repeat what I said above. How you organize your projects is your affair, but keeping classes in their original packages is a *requirement.* Observe it. You can't serialize class `x.C` and expect to deserialize it as `y.C` where `x` and `y` are two different packages. It doesn't work like that. It's serialized as what it is, not what you want it to be. There is nothing 'useless' about a package that is required to exist.

Comment: thanks. It seems that security is the most important thing. I will observe this rule.

Comment: It has nothing to do with security. It is just a rule of the language. Two classes in different packages are different, whatever their names and whatever they contain. Nothing else would make sense.